# How to get a value from an edited TextBox before a ListBox item is selected?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, binding

I have a Silverlight application with a formular. The formular has a TextBox and a ListBox.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ListBox>
```

I focus the TextBox and write something into it. After this I select an item in the ListBox. The ViewModel seems to set "SelectedItem" BEFORE "Value". Why? How can I fix the order? I mean I need to process the TextBox before the ListBox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that looks like a bug. Same example on `WPF` will cause the `TextBox` to be set before the `ListBox`. You would have to find another way of doing what you want by slightly changing the logic of how you app UI functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your `TextBox` `Text` property binding on `TextChanged` event, not `LostFocus` how it is now. [Here](http://zoltanarvai.com/2009/07/22/binding-update-on-textbox-textchanged-event-using-behaviors/) is a sample.

Comment: Are you sure you're using it right? Because with this behavior your `Value` will be updated every time you write something, and it will be before you select your `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

The TextboxBinding is by default updating on LostFocus, try changing your binding to this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}/> 
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"> 
</ListBox>
```